# How to specify complex form validations in Play 2?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I understand how to add simple form validations in Play 2 such as `nonEmptyText`, but how would I implement more complex validations such as "at least one of the fields must be defined"?  Presently I throw an exception in my model object if it gets initialized with all `None`s, but this generates a nasty error message.  I would prefer to get a friendly error message on the form page.

Comment: Is this question applicable for Play v1 or Play v2!?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can nest the `mappings`/`tuples` in your form definition and add `verifying` rules on mapping, sub-mapping, tuple and sub-tuple.
Then in your templates you can retrieve the errors using `form.errors("fieldname")` for a specific field or a group a fields.

For example :

```
val signinForm: Form[Account] = Form(
    mapping(
        "name" -> text(minLength=6, maxLength=50),
        "email" -> email,
        "password" -> tuple(
            "main" -> text(minLength=8, maxLength=16),
            "confirm" -> text
        ).verifying(
            // Add an additional constraint: both passwords must match
            "Passwords don't match", password => password._1 == password._2
        )
    )(Account.apply)(Account.unapply)
)
```

If you have two different passwords, you can retrieve the error in your template using `form.errors("password")`

*In this example, you will have to write your own `Account.apply` and `Account.unapply` to handle `(String, String, (String, String))`*

Comment: Cool but unfortunately this also means that Account can't be a case class.  I don't think case classes can redefine unapply.

Comment: @schmmd in fact Account.apply is a method of the companion object of the case class -> http://daily-scala.blogspot.fr/2009/09/companion-object.html. You can write your own.

Comment: Sure, but my problem is `unapply` not `apply`.

Comment: You are right. You can still have Account as a case class and define a custom Account => Option(String, String, (String, String)) in the Form. Form(...)(Account.apply)((account: Account) => Option(account.name, account.mail, ("", "")).

Comment: I did some digging on the same issue and found that you can use the above approach with a transform() function at the end to turn the tuple back to a single string. This enables using the default apply/unapply functions. See my answer where I posed this tweak.

Answer (score 7):

I have improved upon @kheraud's accepted answer. You can take the tuple and transform it back to a single string. This allows you to use the default apply/unapply functions.

Example :

```
val signinForm: Form[Account] = Form(
    mapping(
        "name" -> text(minLength=6, maxLength=50),
        "email" -> email,
        "password" -> tuple(
            "main" -> text(minLength=8, maxLength=16),
            "confirm" -> text
        ).verifying(
            // Add an additional constraint: both passwords must match
            "Passwords don't match", password => password._1 == password._2
        ).transform(
            { case (main, confirm) => main },
            (main: String) => ("", "")
        )
    )(Account.apply)(Account.unapply)
)
```

Comment: +1 for the transform - haven't seen that until now - it could be a very handy thing to have for all those edge cases that inevitably pop up. Thanks!

Comment: This is perfect as you don't have to change the case class.

Answer (score 0):

In Play! Framework, you can show friendly error messages by the use of flash variable. You just need to write something like;

```
flash.error("Oops. An error occurred");
```

to your controller. Where this error message will reside on the html page should be set with for example;

```
<h1>${flash.error}</h1>
```

Play! Framework will put the error message where it finds this ${flash.error} thing.